# Toolbar not hiding with Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am attempting to replicate behaviour discussed in [this blog post](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/), where the toolbar will hide as I scroll down a RecyclerView (In a seperate fragment), with the tabs remaining.

Unfortnately, after a lot of playing around, I can not seem to get the toolbar to move, and just remains static. I have attached the XML for both my activity, and my fragment.

Thanks for your help and if you need anymore code just ask!

**Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mainPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.test.redditclient.Fragment_Posts">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_posts_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_posts"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
        android:name="info.test.redditclient.Fragment_Bottom_Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_toolbar"></fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:**

after some suggestions, for my activity layout, I have moved the viewpager outside of the AppBarLayout, and also removed a redudant framelayout. Problem still persists.

Comment: Do you add fragment to frame layout with id "container"?

Comment: Apologies, no. That is the container for my NavigationDrawer. The fragments are added using my custom Pager Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

I was using a pre 22.2.0 RecyclerView, which doesn't work.

I solved this by changing my Gradle build:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: `23.0.0` is the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Move your view pager outside the AppBarLayout

Comment: Thanks, that definitely should not have been there. However, it has not solved my problem. It has actually moved my FAB from another fragment slightly off screen. http://i.imgur.com/UvBu4CQ.png.